# Show by Local Class Field Theory $\mathbf Q_p$ has unique Galois ext. iso. to $(Z/2Z)^2$ if $p > 2$, and unique Galois ext. iso. to $(Z/2Z)^3$ o/w.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, alternative-proof, class-field-theory, local-field

Show that $\mathbf{Q}_p$ has a unique Galois extension isomorphic to $(Z/2Z)^2$
if $p > 2$, and that $\mathbf{Q}_2$ has a
unique Galois extension isomorphic to $(Z/2Z)^3$

I have already completed this exercise using regular methods (hensel to classify all quadratic extensions). I have been instructed to use local class field theory but I am unsure on how to make use of things such as Artin reciprocity as I'm not sure how the norm function behaves.

Comment: I am not very conversant with class field theory, but aren't you supposed to study the quotient group of the multiplicative group moded out by the squares: $\mathbf{Q}_p^*/(\mathbf{Q}_p^*)^2$. Either to apply Kummer or to identify the possibilities for the norm subgroup? When the Galois group has exponent two the norm group should contain all the squares, right?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen yeah so thats how I did it originally. Noticed that quadractic extensions correspond with cosets of Q∗p/(Q∗p)^2 and then classify those using hensels lemma. But I dont think thats what my instructor wants here (this exercise was explicitly given a 2nd time)